# ts-node-dev bad option: --transpileOnly and bad option: --ignoreWatch

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, zsh, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run a script for my node server on top of ts-node-dev with two parameters: --transpileOnly and --ignoreWatch. However I am getting the following errors:

[image: Print Error]

My package.json:

[image]

ps: I'm using yarn and node installed by brew on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The problem is that: `--transpileOnly` has been made obsolete. Try using `--transpile-only` now.